# Does Perl initialize variables in a sub that returns nothing before the declaration of the variables

Tags: perl

```
sub Thing {
  my $self = shift;
  if ($self->{validationTest} != 1) {return;}     

  my $data = 'Hello, World!';
  return $data;    
}
```

What happens to $data if the IF conditional is true and the sub is returned early?

Comment: Nothing...the code does not get executed...there is no alternate universe where $data is pre-defined without the if block getting evaluated first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*You ask when the initialization of the variable occurs, but I think you are talking about the assignment of the string `Hello, World!` to `$data`. I'm answering that.*]

The assignment occurs when the assignment is evaluated, which is never if the sub returns before reaching the assignment.

Answer (score -2):

When the `if` condition is true, `Thing()` returns `undef`. The variable `$data` is not even created.

Comment: That is incorrect. `$data` is created when `my` is compiled, and it was either cleared or re-created the last time its scope (the sub) was exited (depending on its value). This is why `{ my $x; sub foo { ... $x ... } }` works.

Comment: No, it's not. Perl is much more complex than that. Each sub has its own symbol table and a variable does not exist until its `my` statement is encountered. There was a bug in older perls that caused variables to be retained. This bug has been changed to a feature using the `state` keyword. Space for non-`state` variables are kept between sub calls but they are marked as not existing. Closures work because a reference to the sub, which contains a reference to its symbol table, keep its symbol table around. Subs must be able to dynamically create their symbol tables or recursion will not work.

Comment: Re "*There was a bug in older perls that caused variables to be retained.*", No, variables being retained wasn't a bug. That implementation was intentional, it's still being used today, and there's no plans to remove it. `state` was introduced to replace buggy code (in programs, not `perl`) that used a variable without first evaluating its `my`, which has always been undefined behaviour.

Comment: (You can see the variable persisting between calls to a sub using `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'sub f { my $x; Dump($x); $x = "abc"; $x .= "d"; } f() for 1..2;'`)

Comment: Re "*Closures work because a reference to the sub, which contains a reference to its symbol table, keep its symbol table around.*", Pretty much spot on. (It's not a symbol table, but a list of arrays called "PAD". PADs are indexed by number, and can contain things that don't map to symbols.) In these PADs are where lexical var exists when the sub isn't being executed.

Comment: Re "*Subs must be able to dynamically create their symbol tables or recursion will not work.*", That's why there's a list of PADs. A sub has a PAD for each level of recursion ever attained.

Comment: Re: "A sub has a PAD for each level of recursion ever attained." Sounds like a memory leek to me.

Comment: No, leaked memory is unreachable memory. This memory is still reachable. Future calls to the sub will use those PADs. Furthermore, deallocatng the sub will also deallocate the PADs. Think of it like a buffer; you might not be using it all currently, but that doesn't mean there's no reason for the extra space.